# Programmatically Create Forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I want to build a program to fill a template, save it in a application specific format and send it to a remote server.

There will be more than one template, each of which have different number of fields to be filled. Moreover, human recognizable names of those fields also will be different from each other.

Moreover, kinds of templates that this program will allow user to fill is not fixed at programming time. There will be additional templates as users deem necessary.

Currently, I am able to load a single template, parse it to see necessary fields to be filled, fill them from mock data and save them.

How can I dynamically create a user form with necessary field names each time a different template selected, so that users can manually enter data?

Comment: Look at the form auto generated code, there is nothing that prevents you to do all that manually. Just click on InitializeComponent() and hit F12 in Visual Studio.

Comment: I can't do that statically, It has to be done that on run time because, users can create their own template formats and load them to program

Comment: @yasar - You can certainly do what Isma suggests at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

To create a form on run time:

```
Form newForm = new Form();
```

To add controls to the form, for example, a text box:

```
TextBox text = new TextBox();

newForm.Controls.Add(text);
```

You can also add controls to other containers, e.g.:

```
GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox();

groupBox.Controls.Add(text);

newForm.Controls.Add(groupBox);
```

Now the groupbox will be added to the form containing a text box.

Comment: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Form' could not be found `

Answer (score 0):

Try this little program:

```
var form = new Form();

var label = new Label() { Text = "Name", Location = new Point(10, 10), AutoSize = true };
var textbox = new TextBox() { Location = new Point(60, 10) };
var button = new Button() { Text = "Save", Location = new Point(10, 35) };

button.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("You typed " + textbox.Text);

form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textbox, button });

form.Show();
```

Comment: I can do this with a loop foreach field name, but, how can I get specific textbox that corresponds to a field when the user clicks generate?

Comment: @yasar - If you're doing this in a loop then use a `for` loop and an array to store the textboxes in the array.

Comment: @yasar you have to assign each control an event handler; since the event handler will probably be the same for all - say - textboxes, within the method you have to understand who is the caller, by casting the `sender` argument to the right type (and then read properties like name or tag that you previously assigned).

Comment: @ccalboni - You don't need to do that if you're creating events like the one in my answer. You can ignore the sender and specifically reference the created controls. Just like the `textbox.Text` reference inside the `button.Click` handler.

Comment: my form flashes for a second then disappears...

Comment: @johnk - Sounds like the app is exiting. How have you set up the app?